# Is a battery designed for UPS usable for an RV?

Tags: batteries

My sister and her boyfriend just bought an RV from an old Polish Grandpa. It isn't a ”real" campe, the Polish grandpa turned a van into an RV with his own hands.
My sister started to refurbish it, and she found that this battery is used for services:
-Datasafe HX500
-12V 506W/Cell 15 min
Searching on the internet I found out that it is a battery that is used for UPS, so I wonder if it is suitable for use for an RV. If so, how do you transform that 506W/Cell 15 min to find the battery capacity in Ah?

Comment: You have to look at the spec sheet for the battery vs. the loads you want to power.  With DIY off-grid power projects, battery sizing mistakes are very common for a bunch of reasons - even when the person is an expert, loads are added or removed, one guesses wrong how often they'll use them, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Is is usable?  yes.

Is it suitable? probably.

Is it ideal?  Commercial RVs are bult to a price with often the cheapest parts that can get them off the showroom floor, this UPS batter could well be better than a typical RV battery, I can't say for sure.

But I'm guessing you're looking to replace it because batteries don't last forever.

The real question is how many Ah you need, not how many this battery once had.

Anyway lead acid is 2V per cell, so

500W / 2V  is 250A
that for a quarter hour is gets you 62.5 Ah

This will be an under-estimate as general purpose lead acid batteries are measured in a 20 hour discharge, rather than quarter hour (because this slower measure gives bigger numbers).

Measure the size of the space where the battery goes and get a deep discharge battery that fits in that location.